# Displaying details in full after clicking a ListView item in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to xamarin forms and I'm trying to create a simple ToDo List app. I want to show the full details, on a new page, of an item after clicking it on a ListView but i dont know how to go about it. I have a class called ToDoList with get and set methods for string Task and date. In the XAML i have a listview called TaskView and in the XAML.cs page I have ItemTapped method with the following:

```
    private async void TaskView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var details = e.Item as ToDoList;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ToDoDetails()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Im not sure how to go about the rest

Comment: Xamarin has a number of existing ToDo samples - have you looked at them?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/todo/

Comment: Have you set the ItemsSource and Is the List visible? If you are learning Xamarin, use Jason's suggested tutorial link.

Comment: Let me check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sample `OnItemSelected` method is as follow :

```
async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var item = args.SelectedItem as Item;
    if (item == null)
        return;

    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailPage(new ItemDetailViewModel(item)));

    // Manually deselect item.
    ItemsListView.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

And when navigating to `ItemDetailPage.cs` :

```
public partial class ItemDetailPage : ContentPage
{
    ItemDetailViewModel viewModel;

    public ItemDetailPage(ItemDetailViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public ItemDetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var item = new Item
        {
            Text = "Item 1",
            Description = "This is an item description."
        };

        viewModel = new ItemDetailViewModel(item);
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}    public partial class ItemDetailPage : ContentPage
{
    ItemDetailViewModel viewModel;

    public ItemDetailPage(ItemDetailViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public ItemDetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var item = new Item
        {
            Text = "Item 1",
            Description = "This is an item description."
        };

        viewModel = new ItemDetailViewModel(item);
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

**By the way** , the easy way to implement the **ToDoList** application , you can create a new **Master-Detail** app in Visual Studio 2019 to research that .

Step One :

[image]

Step two :

[image]

Step three :

[image]

Now , you will see the folder of project that how to implement the To-Do-List function :

[image]